# How to get React.memo functionality to work with children?

Tags: reactjs

I have a stateless functional component `<Sidebar/>`which simply returns its children in a div. This component is rendered by `<App/>` which maintains its own state, and passes an element of that state 'over the top' of Sidebar into one of its children.

```
const Sidebar = React.memo(({children}) => {
  return <div className='sidebar'>{children}</div>
})

const App = (props) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  setInterval(() => {setCounter(counter => counter+1}), 1000)
  return (
    <Sidebar>
      <ChildOne counter={counter}/>
    </Sidebar>
  )
}
```

Despite using React.memo on `<Sidebar>` it re-renders every time the state changes. I've done a bit of reading and experimentation and the problem seems to be that when `<ChildOne/>` updates its state, React is actually creating a brand new object, and so even shallow comparison shows the children as changing, thus Sidebar re-renders.

How can I get Sidebar to stop re-rendering?

Comment: Have you tried using `memo`, can you show us that code?

Comment: I have edited the code to make it more explicit.

Comment: It is very difficult to say what is going wrong without looking at your implementation. I have tried to recreate the issue using internal state in `ChildOne` and also memoizing the `Sidebar`. Here is the implementation [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-ishizaka-wspve?file=/src/Sidebar.js). Have a look at the console, in my case `Sidebar` never rendered. You can edit the sandbox to recreate the issue using your implementaion.

Comment: I realised I had oversimplified the scenario. I have edited - hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

From [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) docs

> React.memo only checks for prop changes. If your function component
>   wrapped in React.memo has a useState or useContext Hook in its
>   implementation, it will still rerender when state or context change.

In your case, children which is a prop, is re-rendered each time `counter` changes, so there's no memoization.

The only solution I see, is to not pass a state value to the sidebar children. If you need to interpolate a value only for the first time, then use refs, not state values.

Comment: How is it that shallow comparison between the children shows up the child's change in props exactly?